How to I tell cargo to use a custom build target?
I am currently following this tutorial on making a simple rust OS.
As the author instructs, I created a json file named x86_64-simple_os.json with the following contents:
{
    "llvm-target": "x86_64-unknown-none",
    "data-layout": "e-m:e-p270:32:32-p271:32:32-p272:64:64-i64:64-i128:128-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128",
    "arch": "x86_64",
    "target-endian": "little",
    "target-pointer-width": "64",
    "target-c-int-width": "32",
    "os": "none",
    "executables": true,
    "linker-flavor": "ld.lld",
    "linker": "rust-lld",
    "panic-strategy": "abort",
    "disable-redzone": true,
    "features": "-mmx,-sse,+soft-float"
}

I also have a TOML file at .cargo/config.toml with the following contents:
[unstable]
build-std = ["core", "compiler_builtins"]

[build]
target = "x86_64-simple_os.json"

My Cargo.toml file contains:
[package]
name = "simple_os"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[profile.dev]
panic = "abort"

[profile.release]
panic = "abort"

[dependencies]

And I have a rust-toolchain file that specifies that I am using the nightly build.
At the point in the tutorial that I am at (here), I should be expecting it to build. Or if I try to back up a step and  remove [unstable] build-std = ["core", "compiler_builtins"] I should get the following error:
> cargo build --target x86_64-simple_os.json

error[E0463]: can't find crate for `core`

However, I am only getting the following error:
$ cargo build --target x86_64-simple_os.json
error: failed to run `rustc` to learn about target-specific information

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `C:\Users\12081\.rustup\toolchains\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\bin\rustc.exe - --crate-name ___ --print=file-names --target '\\?\C:\Users\12081\OSTutorial\simple_os\x86_64-simple_os.json' --crate-type bin --crate-type rlib --crate-type dylib --crate-type cdylib --crate-type staticlib --crate-type proc-macro --print=sysroot --print=split-debuginfo --print=crate-name --print=cfg` (exit code: 1)
  --- stderr
  error: Error loading target specification: expected value at line 1 column 1. Run `rustc --print target-list` for a list of built-in targets

I took a look online and the only time that I found anything even remotely related to my issue was when I started reading this question. However, not only is that question and it's associated answer from almost 7 years ago, but the tutorial has an entirely new version, with updates from 8 months ago.
When I do try the suggestions in the answer from the other question, I get the same error as before.
(Edited to fix broken link)

Just a hunch, since you're working on windows, do you have windows line endings (CRLF) in your target JSON file?

That is quite possible, I am not sure how to tell or how to change it if that is an issue

@mhutter I just tested things by having git replace the line endings to LF with no success. Then I tried again with CRLF and still got the same
